# How can I test full page response?

Tags: php, phpunit

I need to know how I can test views or full pages responses. Testing small parts is easy, but I need test a big value too. For instance, I have a controller that creates a select with 100 options, and I print it on view. How can I test it contents? I really need create a file with this content, or exists a better way, like a visual test?

Answer (score 0):

Two great tools may assist you: www.saucelabs.com and Selenium builder for Firefox.

You can export recorded scripts to Sauce's input format.

There is a coupon code for 20 unexpiration hours of free testing, if you want so :) (I found on the web).

Comment: I will check that tools. Thanks.